# publish static website with images on drive

Tags: html, css, google-drive-api

I have 2 questions to ask, one is how can I publish my website correctly on google drive so I can give people in my company a link and they can view the webpage perfectly fine,two is its only 1 index.html and abit of javascript with some images, so I know it will work because it does not require php or any type of sql, but my issue is in terms of the images that are generated through a relative path in css using background url attribute, the images will now be on drive but I am unable to find a way to get absolute links of those images so i can use that in my code instead, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a new folder in your google drive and put all your images in that folder, share that folder publically.

You can browse the image inside that folder like googledrive.com/host/your_public_folder_id/your_imgage_name.jpg

Answer (score 0):

best way I have found to display images on HTML page is

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=Your_Image_ID" alt="" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this website, it generates a direct permalink for a public google drive image: http://gdurl.com/. Have in mind that Google limits the amount of traffic to your files (whether via gdURL or directly from Drive). Once too much bandwidth or too many views have occurred for a file, Google will stop allowing people to load it temporarily.

Comment: Great - this works. Part of problem was that url worked at first then stopped working, so will post back here if anything changes. Thanks